# Error making app compatible for iOS6 and iOS7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios6, ios7

I built an app on XCode 5 for iOS7 and have just downloaded the iOS6 SDK so I can make the app compatible for iOS6, however when trying to build the project I am getting this error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "___sincos_stret",
```

What should I do to solve this because I really need my app working with iOS6

Here are my current settings:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`__sincos_stret` is new to iOS7. Make sure your deployment target is set to iOS6. See semi-related question here: [___sincos_stret undefined symbol when linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015780/sincos-stret-undefined-symbol-when-linking)

**Update**: You need to set the Base SDK to iOS 7. You generally want to set Base SDK to the latest version you intend support, and Deployment Target to the earliest version. See related question: [Base versus Active versus Deployment target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358033/iphone-base-versus-active-versus-deployment-target)

Comment: I have tried that, but it's still giving me the error. Please see my edited question with screenshots. Is there anything else I should change?

Comment: You have set your Base SDK to iOS 6.  The iOS 6 SDK is not supported in Xcode 5, and you can't use it if you want to deploy an iOS 7 app.  (Also, starting Feb. 1, all apps must be submitted with Xcode 5 and the iOS 7 SDK.)

Comment: Think of it this way: Base SDK is the *newest* iOS version you support; deployment target is the *oldest* version you support.

Answer (score 2):

set the Base SDK to ios7 and set the deployment target to ios6

that way you get the headers for 7 but the app is compiled to be run on ios6