# c++ libstd compute sin and cos simultaneously

Tags: c++, math, libstdc++, trigonometry

In C library `math.h`, there was a `sincos` function which was pretty efficient, because it computed both sine and cosine in a time closer to a single call to `sin()` or `cos()` than to the total time of calling both.

Is there such function in C++ standard library?

Comment: here are a few pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683588/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-compute-sin-and-cos-together

Comment: Well actually I already have my own sincos SSE optimized functions, but here I'm writing an example plugin and I want to make it as simple as possible using no other library than the standard library

Comment: GCC at a low level of optimization (`-O1`) and, in general `-Ofast` will do this for you. https://godbolt.org/z/jCiTDo

Comment: I'd profile [`std::exp(I * angle)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/exp), or look at what code it generates - hopefully a (possibly internal) optimized `sincos` function. In any case, it won't be any worse than separate calls to `sin` and `cos`, and should avoid the numerical instabilities in trying to derive one from the other by trig identities.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is there no such function in c++ standard library?

No, unfortunately there isn't.

> In C library math.h, there was a sincos function

On Linux, it is available as [GNU Extension](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sincos.3.html). It's not standard in C either.

Answer (score 6):

Just use sin and cos separately and turn on optimizations. C compilers are pretty good at optimizing, and they will probably realize that you are computing both the sine and cosine of the same variable. If you want to make **sure**, you can allways inspect the resulting assembly (for gcc use the -S option) and see what did it generate.

The compiler will probably optimize away any calls to `sin` or `cos` in favour of simply using SSE intructions to calculate it. I'm not sure SSE has a `sincos` opcode but even calculating them separatly is faster than calling any `sincos` function that the compiler won't optimize out.

Comment: SSE has no support for sin/cos or any "fancy" function beyond division and square root. But some compilers (such as the Intel Compiler) will have a vectorized implementation that uses SSE.

Comment: Are compilers really able to do high level optimizations? sin and cos are call to functions, not arithmetic operators.

Comment: SSE has no sin, cos or sincos instructions. Only base arithmetics.

Comment: @galinette: sin and cos are treated specially by the compiler and optimized out when optimizations are enabled, and yes it seems SSE has no sin or cos functions (I remembered wrong), so it's the x87 instructions of course.

Comment: Using godbolt I confirmed that newer GCC versions at high optimization levels do manage to coalesce sin + cos to sincos, but clang and VS2017 have no such optimization.

Comment: @DanOlson, I think MSVC 2017 and above does optimize Sine and Cosine calls: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-code-optimizer-improvements-in-visual-studio-2017-versions-15-5-and-15-3/

Comment: @DanOlson, confirmed here https://godbolt.org/z/wuS26Z for GCC and intel at a fairly low level of optimization. clang does the optimization only in `-Ofast` (fast-math). This hints me that `sincos` may not guarantee the *exact* same result as `sin` and `cos` called separately.

Comment: This answer is more useful than the other one. It is a pity that it was downvoted for a technical reason. I would suggest removing the controversial assertion about SSE.

Comment: As more you digg into it as more it gets complicated... I've tested various combinations on [quick-bench.com](https://quick-bench.com/q/PFBg_CCf1N4T81xxWBnXiYtC6ec). By default sin() and cos() may have _side effects_ (error codes), so they will be executed twize in the expression `x=sin(x)+sin(x);`. This behaviour is also disabled with `-Ofast`. gcc seems to disable it also in `-O3` for _sin_ and _cos_. Thus it is **14x faster** to evaluate `cos(x) * cos(x)` compared to `sin(x) * cos(x)` (gcc 10.1 with -O3).

Answer (score 6):

While there is no standard C++ library function, you can define a template function pretty quickly:

```cpp
template <class S>
std::pair<S,S> sincos(S arg) { return { std::sin(arg), std::cos(arg) }; }
```

You can then get the result on a single line (with C++ 17) with:

```cpp
auto [s, c] = sincos(arg);
```

It's very convenient if you are doing this often, saves space, and is self-documenting, so I would highly recommend it.
If you're worried about performance, don't.  When compiled with optimizations, it should produce the exact same code as calling sin and cos separately.  You can confirm this is the case with `clang++ -std=c++17 -S -o - -c -O3 sincos.cpp` on the following test code:

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <class S>
std::pair<S,S> sincos(S arg) { return { std::sin(arg), std::cos(arg) }; }

void testPair(double a) {
    auto [s,c] = sincos(a);
    std::cout << s << ", " << c << '\n';
}

void testSeparate(double a) {
    double s = std::sin(a);
    double c = std::cos(a);
    std::cout << s << ", " << c << '\n';
}
```

On MacOS with clang, both test functions compile to the exact same assembly (minus the name changes) that call `___sincos_stret` to perform the combined computation (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19017286/973580).

Comment: godbolt showing that at -O3 we get the desired assembly: https://godbolt.org/z/KdT9fjEEr

Comment: So the compiler is smart enough to call an an optimized version if sincos when it sees them in pairs like this? @godbolt asm shows a call  `sincos`, so we assume that this will be the more efficient function? That is cool if true.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such built-in standard function. Here's direct assembly code to compute sincos at once (`gcc` syntax)

This is only when needing 80 bit precision. There's no vectorization with x87 instructions so it won't improve the performance unless `long double` is needed(and it's actually using 80 bits). Even then separate `sinl` and `cosl` will be optimized to such a result as below.

**It's not a good practice(neither using assembly directly or x87 in most cases)** ...but it was a fun exercise so here's the result.

```cpp
long double input = 5L;

long double sin = input;
long double cos = 0L;
__asm__ (
    "fldt %0;"
    "fsincos;" // sincos in one instruction
    "fstpt %1;"
    "fstpt %0;"
    : "+m" (sin), "+m" (cos)
);
printf("sin %.19Lf cos %.19Lf \n", sin, cos);
```

Comment: The OP was asking for a function/code based on the C++ standard library.

Answer (score -1):

Instead, you can use this function which only uses std::cos and std::sqrt (haven't actually tested it, it may not work)

```
template <typename T>
constexpr inline static void sincos(const T &x, T* sin, T* cos) {
    (*cos) = std::cos(x);
    (*sin) = std::sqrt(static_cast<T>(1) - *cos**cos);
    if ((int)(x / M_PI) & 1) (*sin) = -(*sin);
}
```

Comment: The result of that will have poor precision at some inputs (try it with 1e-6) and is likely to be much slower than just using sin and cos.