# cannot import Scipy.special on Mac OS 10.8.5

Tags: python, xcode, macos, scipy

I'm using Python 2.7 on MacOSX 10.8.5. I installed Scipy (0.14.0.dev-dc14aee) via ScipySuperpack-10.8_final. Now I'm trying to import "Scipy.special" but I failed.

```
import numpy as np    
import scipy    
from scipy import special
```

Then,

```
ImportError                               
Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-1-f54905432611> in <module>()    
    1 import numpy as np
    2 import scipy
----> 3 from scipy import special
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.14.0.dev_dc14aee-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/scipy/special/__init__.py in <module>()
530 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
531 
--> 532 from ._ufuncs import *
533 
534 from .basic import *

ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.14.0.dev_dc14aee-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/scipy/special/_ufuncs.so, 2): Symbol not found: ___sincos_stret
Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.14.0.dev_dc14aee-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/scipy/special/_ufuncs.so
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.14.0.dev_dc14aee-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/scipy/special/_ufuncs.so
```

I checked [the another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553332/using-custom-built-opencv-for-ios-on-xcode-produces-sincos-stret-undefined-sy) about X-code version related to "Symbol not found: ___sincos_stret". Exactly, my Xcode is 5.1.1 and command line tools have been installed. But I could not find a link to old Xcode for replacement.

```
$ xcode-select --print-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

I tried to install scipy via pip as well. It had many problems for installation, so I avoided using "pip install scipy".

How should I resolve the problem?

Comment: Try `pip install --user scipy` again. If it doesn't work, see http://scipy.org/install.html for other options.

Comment: Why are the error messages referring to `macosx-10.9` but you're running 10.85?  Are you sure you're importing the correct packages?

Comment: I downloaded a soruce code for os 10.8 from here. "Dependencies: OS X 10.7 Lion, Python 2.7, Xcode 4.3.2 " (Readme)

https://github.com/fonnesbeck/ScipySuperpack/releases/tag/10.8_final